# Display checkbox and label on the same line

Tags: html, css

I am trying to display checkbox followed by a label on the same line. This is my code.

```html
<div class="checkbox">
  <label>
    Internal Org Person:
    <input type="checkbox" path="isInternalOrgPerson" id="isInternalOrgPerson" value="">
  </label>
</div>
```

but checkbox is not aligned with label.

Edit: I added the style but it is displaying on the next line. It is a popup window. Do I have to change the label's properties? Here is my full code:

```
<form:form method="get" modelAttribute="newAddress"
                action="/project/add">
                <div class="modal fade" id="addUser" role="dialog">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">

                        <!-- Add User Modal content-->
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                <h4 class="modal-title">Add User</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <spring:bind path="firstName">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="newFirstName">First Name:</label>
                                        <form:input path="firstName" type="text" class="form-control"
                                            id="firstname" placeHolder="First Name" />
                                    </div>
                                </spring:bind>
                                <spring:bind path="lastName">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="newLastName">Last Name:</label>
                                        <form:input path="lastName" type="text" class="form-control"
                                            id="lastName" placeHolder="Last Name" />
                                    </div>
                                </spring:bind>
                                <spring:bind path="address">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="newEmail">Email Address:</label>
                                        <form:input path="address" type="text" class="form-control"
                                            id="address" placeHolder="email@dn.xyz" />
                                    </div>
                                </spring:bind>
                                <spring:bind path="isInternalOrgPerson">
                                <div class="checkbox">
                                <label>
                                        Internal Org Person:
                                <input type="checkbox" path="isInternalOrgPerson" id="isInternalOrgPerson" value="">
                                </label>
                                </div>
                                </spring:bind>

                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button id="addUser" type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Add User</button>
                                <button type="but`enter code here`ton" class="btn btn-default"
                                    data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form:form>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your code was always in the question, but was not visible to readers because you had not used the "Format Code Sample" button `{}` on the editor. I have done that for you so it now reads OK. You can press the [edit] button if you need to add any more information to the question.

Comment: Hi hanu, do you feel as if I answered your question completely? If so, please don’t forget to mark my answer as "accepted" by clicking the gray checkmark to the left of the answer. If your question hasn't been fully answered, please elaborate on what else you need to know so the community can provide you with further help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To get the checkbox to line up, you can use the `vertical-align: bottom` style on the checkbox input element. To prevent the checkbox from wrapping onto the next line, you can also use `white-space: nowrap` on your containing element (in this case the label).

Here is a live example:

```css
#isInternalOrgPerson {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

#isInternalOrgPersonLabel {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="checkbox">
  <label id="isInternalOrgPersonLabel">
    Internal Org Person:
    <input type="checkbox" path="isInternalOrgPerson" id="isInternalOrgPerson" value="">
  </label>
</div>
```